# where to put wordpress htaccess on openshift

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, openshift

I have cloned my wordpress application from openshift with git, in my cloned application there is php folder, when i put my htaccess file in it then i commit my changes like this :

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'ok'
git push
```

My htaccess file is not pushed in the application repository folder on openshift, but when i put it via ftp with filezilla it works, not with git.

I don't know where i have to put .htaccess file ? if it is in php folder, why it's not uploaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used our official quickstart, you would need to use an action_hook (probably deploy) to copy a .htaccess file into place, otherwise the files are actually not stored in a place that is affected by git.  You could also try using this quickstart( https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-wordpress-developer-quickstart) where EVERYTHING except for uploads, is stored in git (plugins, themes, etc)

Comment: Yes i've used the official quickstart, i've never used action_hook befor, can you give me an example how to use it to copy htaccess file ? thanks

Comment: Thank you i've finnaly moved htaccess file in deploy hook to destination folder, now it works, many thanks

Comment: which location you moved .htaccess to?